# Easier jQuery function for fadeIn() or other .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is an easier way of calling everything on a page, and telling it to fadeIn all at the same time. This is what I've come up with, but it gets pretty lengthy

```
var $from1 = {opacity: 0};
var $to1 = {opacity: 1};

$('.navbar').css($from1).animate($to1, 2000);

var $from2 = {opacity: 0};
var $to2 = {opacity: 1};

$('.brand h1').css($from2).animate($to2, 2000);

var $from3 = {opacity: 0};
var $to3 = {opacity: 1};

$('.bgimage').css($from3).animate($to3, 2000);

var $from4 = {opacity: 0};
var $to4 = {opacity: 1};

$('.bgimage-media').css($from4).animate($to4, 2000);

var $from5 = {opacity: 0};
var $to5 = {opacity: 1};

$('.bgimage-contact').css($from5).animate($to5, 2000);
```

Comment: Need HTML and CSS in order to realize the possibilities of how jQuery can be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css3 transition.
Give your desired transition effects to a class and add that class to the element.
Once the class is added all the animations will happen smoothly without using any javascript.

Or you can use keyframe animations of css3

Comment: Yea that sounds a lot easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid using JavaScript for making things that you can easily do with CSS**, If you certainly need to use Javascript, add all Transitions to a CSS class and Add or Remove that class with JavaScript, that would use really less memory, you can use Transition in the classes, you just one animating + one fadein, you can put it in a CSS and add that class to all of the Selectors want to be faded-in: this is Simple example for what I mean from W3Schools, try and play with this to get the concept, this will use much less memory for what you doing and using GPU instead, so make things much faster + better performance :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```